# Why am I getting an invalid lvalue in increment error

Tags: c, pointers

here is my code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void)
    {
          int x[] = {10,20,30};
          *(x) ++;
     }
```

When i try to compile this, I get an error "invalid lvalue in increment". I don't understand why there is any invalid value. I know that array name is a pointer to the first element i the array. Isn't 
*(x) ++ the same as *(x) = *(x) + 1? So x[0] will now be 11. Is there something i am missing? I am not changing the array pointer. I know that would be an error.

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Comment: Didn't work. I have the right idea here don't I ?

Comment: My bad, change to `(*x)++;` The post increment operator binds more tightly than the dereference operator, so the parentheses around `*x` are required.

Comment: or change to `++*x;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post-increment operator (`expr++`) binds more tightly than the dereference operator, so you need parentheses around the `*x`. This is what you need:

```
(*x)++;
```

Without them, you're trying to increment `x`, and then dereference it. Since `x` is an array, and is therefore not modifiable, that's why you're getting your error, because `x++` is not allowed.

Comment: does bind more tightly just mean precedence?

Comment: Yes, it means the `x` and the `++` get put together before the `x` and the `*` do.

Answer (score 1):

An array's name is an lvalue which can't be modified in C, hence your error.

With regard to:

> Isn't *(x) ++ the same as *(x) = *(x) + 1?

The answer is "No". `++` (postifix increment) operator has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `*` (dereferencing). So

```
*(x) ++;
```

is equivalent to

```
*(x++);
```

---

You could do:

```
(*x)++;
```

or another way would be (*much easier* to read one IMO ;-)

```
x[0]++;
```